# React Native upgrade to 0.22.2 throws NetInfo error

Tags: react-native

today I have decided to update react-native package in my project...

```
npm install react-native@0.22.2
```

Now I'm getting an error on android...

```
NetInfo.getCurrentConnectivity got 0 arguments, expected 2
```

It is failing on this simple code...

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
  console.log('First, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
});
```

This is my build.gradle...

```
compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1'
```

I tried this:

```
compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:*'
```

but `react-native run-android` started to fail.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to run `react-native upgrade`

and override files in

```
android/build.gradle 
android/app/react.gradle
```

Comment: Yeah, I've already done that and everything began to work. Thanks

Comment: I've noticed that pre-lollipop Android version keeps throwing this error.